# How to get URL's from a JSON page where the user searches a word and then appears all the websites with that word?

Tags: shell-script, wget, html

I am trying to use a script in bash shell that returns the present urls on a certain webpage... What I have is a script that returns all URLs but you need to put in the code the link that you want, and I want that the user to put a word and then it returns all the URLs with that word. Like this `./reddit.sh Linux`, and then it shows the URLs with that word. This is the code that I have until now:

```
wget -qO- http://reddit.com/ | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" | sort | unique
```

Comment: Reddit has an API.

Comment: It's not the word on the website... It's like you're on the website and you put linux on the search box and then it gives you all the results on the word linux.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like

```
target="reddit"; wget -qO- http://reddit.com/ | grep -Po "http.*?(?=\")" | grep -i $target | sort | uniq
```

**Edit:** Expanding on the same lines as @RomanPerekhrest

```
target="linux"; wget -qO- "http://reddit.com/search?q=${target}" | grep -Po "http.*?(?=\")" | grep $target | sort -u
```

**Edit on the edit** Multiple words as @nxnev

```
target="arch linux"; url="http://reddit.com/search?q=$target"; search=$(echo $target | sed 's/ /|/'); wget -qO- "$url" | grep -Po "http.*?(?=\")" | grep -Eh "$search" | sort -u
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. It's working now... One more thing, do you know how to shuffle the links with the flag -r and to display a certain amount of links pretended by the user like -n 8 for example?

Comment: This sounds like homework...... lose the sort and pipe through `shuf` and `more`. If you can't work out the syntax from the `man` page then ........

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution:

Used stuff: **bash**, **wget**, **xmllint**, **sed**, **sort**

`reddit.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

search_word="$1"

wget -qO - --follow-tags=a "http://reddit.com/search?q=${search_word}" \
|  xmllint --html --xpath '//a[contains(@href, "'"${search_word}"'")]' - 2>/dev/null \
| sed 's/<\/a>/&\n/g' | sort -u
```

---

Usage:

```
$ bash reddit.sh linux
```

The output(shortened):

```
<a href="https://fossbytes.com/firefox-quantum-57-is-here-to-kill-google-chrome-download-for-windows-mac-linux/" class="search-link may-blank">https://fossbytes.com/firefox-quantum-57-is-here-to-kill-google-chrome-download-for-windows-mac-linux/</a>
<a href="https://www.change.org/p/lenovo-demand-that-lenovo-provide-bios-update-to-enable-linux-installation">https://www.change.org/p/lenovo-demand-that-lenovo-provide-bios-update-to-enable-linux-installation</a>
<a href="https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/atari-are-launching-a-new-gaming-system-the-ataribox-and-it-runs-linux.10418" class="search-link may-blank">https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/atari-are-launching-a-new-gaming-system-the-ataribox-and-it-runs-linux.10418</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/5xyw3c/every_time_i_try_out_linux/" data-inbound-url="/r/funny/comments/5xyw3c/every_time_i_try_out_linux/?utm_term=055776b0-02a3-4fd4-81fb-7693fb1f7a86&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=1" data-href-url="/r/funny/comments/5xyw3c/every_time_i_try_out_linux/" class="search-comments may-blank">2,315 comments</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/5xyw3c/every_time_i_try_out_linux/" data-inbound-url="/r/funny/comments/5xyw3c/every_time_i_try_out_linux/?utm_term=055776b0-02a3-4fd4-81fb-7693fb1f7a86&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=1" data-href-url="/r/funny/comments/5xyw3c/every_time_i_try_out_linux/" class="search-title may-blank">Every time I try out linux</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/6wdq13/20170825_happy_birthday_linux/" data-inbound-url="/r/funny/comments/6wdq13/20170825_happy_birthday_linux/?utm_term=055776b0-02a3-4fd4-81fb-7693fb1f7a86&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=14" data-href-url="/r/funny/comments/6wdq13/20170825_happy_birthday_linux/" class="search-comments may-blank">269 comments</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/6wdq13/20170825_happy_birthday_linux/" data-inbound-url="/r/funny/comments/6wdq13/20170825_happy_birthday_linux/?utm_term=055776b0-02a3-4fd4-81fb-7693fb1f7a86&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=14" data-href-url="/r/funny/comments/6wdq13/20170825_happy_birthday_linux/" class="search-title may-blank">20170825: Happy Birthday Linux</a>
...
```

---

Additional test case, searching for `python`:

```
$ bash reddit.sh python
```

The output(shortened):

```
<a href="https://developers.slashdot.org/story/17/12/15/1133217/microsoft-considers-adding-python-as-an-official-scripting-language-in-excel" class="search-link may-blank">https://developers.slashdot.org/story/17/12/15/1133217/microsoft-considers-adding-python-as-an-official-scripting-language-in-excel</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/ATBGE/comments/7bjnxs/check_out_this_python/" data-inbound-url="/r/ATBGE/comments/7bjnxs/check_out_this_python/?utm_term=02b9b18c-b9c1-42d4-8718-7f5c74d03b90&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=7" data-href-url="/r/ATBGE/comments/7bjnxs/check_out_this_python/" class="search-comments may-blank">302 comments</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/ATBGE/comments/7bjnxs/check_out_this_python/" data-inbound-url="/r/ATBGE/comments/7bjnxs/check_out_this_python/?utm_term=02b9b18c-b9c1-42d4-8718-7f5c74d03b90&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=7" data-href-url="/r/ATBGE/comments/7bjnxs/check_out_this_python/" class="search-title may-blank">Check out this python!</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/5haxy5/monty_python_life_of_brian_is_still_relevant_today/" data-inbound-url="/r/funny/comments/5haxy5/monty_python_life_of_brian_is_still_relevant_today/?utm_term=02b9b18c-b9c1-42d4-8718-7f5c74d03b90&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=8" data-href-url="/r/funny/comments/5haxy5/monty_python_life_of_brian_is_still_relevant_today/" class="search-comments may-blank">1,364 comments</a>
<a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/5haxy5/monty_python_life_of_brian_is_still_relevant_today/" data-inbound-url="/r/funny/comments/5haxy5/monty_python_life_of_brian_is_still_relevant_today/?utm_term=02b9b18c-b9c1-42d4-8718-7f5c74d03b90&amp;utm_medium=search&amp;utm_source=reddit&amp;utm_name=frontpage&amp;utm_content=8" data-href-url="/r/funny/comments/5haxy5/monty_python_life_of_brian_is_still_relevant_today/" class="search-title may-blank">Monty Python Life Of Brian is still relevant today</a>
...
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. It's working now... One more thing, do you know how to shuffle the links with the flag -r and to display a certain amount of links pretended by the user like -n 8 for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show search results (just the URLs) from Reddit but without using their API, this should do the work:

```
reddit() {
  local 'search_term' 'user_agent'
  user_agent='your_user_agent'
  for search_term; do
    curl \
      --data-urlencode "q=${search_term}" \
      --get \
      --header "User-Agent: ${user_agent}" \
      --silent \
      "https://www.reddit.com/search" \
    | grep -P -o -e '<a [^>]*? class="search-title may-blank" >.*?<\/a>' \
    | grep -P -o -e '(?<=href=")(.*?)(?=")' \
    | tail -n '+4'
  done
}
```

Example:

```
$ reddit 'arch linux'
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6pepav/someone_got_offended_by_a_hostname_of_an/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6g6xsu/the_arch_linux_wiki_is_awesome_and_i_would_like/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/7ikqxs/my_new_macbook_pro_has_been_made_glorious_by_the/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5sx15b/arch_linux_pulls_the_plug_on_32bit/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7a4sgv/almost_no_one_on_campus_got_it_but_i_dressed_up/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7blg7w/arch_linux_news_the_end_of_i686_support/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7g53jg/here_is_a_screenshot_of_a_music_player_ive_been/
https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/7k704w/my_beloved_x1_carbon_5th_gen_running_arch_linux/
https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/39hl6h/im_thoroughly_enjoying_arch_linux_60fps/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3qsmk4/twitch_installs_arch_linux_similar_to_twitch/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/7aai76/i_am_using_archlinux/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7j2zhl/fully_encrypted_archlinux_with_secure_boot_on/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/5dbgku/my_experience_with_arch_linux_so_far/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4m0r93/why_did_archlinux_embrace_systemd/
https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/7iss7b/xfce_arch_linux_satisfaction/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5ndu7r/my_manual_to_install_arch_linux_the_minimal_way_i/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/73g3vz/librem_5_will_support_arch_linux/
https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7jyie0/the_arch_linux_community_does_not_look_very_about/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/4xep1o/no_mans_sky_running_on_wine_in_64_bit_arch_linux/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7bjp8j/hexadecimal_arch_linux_calendar_for_2018/
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3r1mdv/twitch_installs_arch_linux_lasts_only_a_few_hours/
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7hfb9m/farch_functional_arch_linux_system_management/
```